# Double-t-on le sujet à l'oral dans les clauses subordonées subjonctives ?

Tags: pronoms, oral, subjonctif, sujet, niveau-de-langue

À l'oral, le sujet est doublé très fréquemment avant une forme d'être :

> ça, c'est ma chaise

ou on n'entend que rarement la pause entre « ça » et « c'est ». (Cela n'est pas commun dans les hauts niveaux de français, mais c'est quasi universel à l'oral dans la langue quotidienne.)  Est-ce que on fait la même chose à l'orale dans les clauses subordonnées ?

> j'ai peur que ça, ce soit ma chaise

ou

> j'ai peur que ce soit ma chaise

Je pense que je n'ai jamais entendu le premier, mais logiquement si l'on dit

> ça c'est

on penserait que l'on dirais

> ça ce soit.

Answer (score 4):

A ma connaissance, cette forme peut être utilisée dans n'importe quelle proposition : principale, relative, conjonctive, etc. Elle dénote une insistance sur le sujet, qui doit être mis en relation avec le contexte pour la comprendre.

> Je sais que Pierre, c'est un imbécile.
>
> Il me semble que la réunion, c'est demain.
>
> Il ne faut pas réveiller votre grand-père qui, lui, somnole dans son fauteuil.

Je recommande la lecture de ce [passage](http://gabrielwyler.com/page461.html#Trace=pronomd%C3%A9monstratifceou%C3%A7a) sur ce site. Non seulement on y trouve beaucoup d'exemples, mais aussi on apprend que cette forme se nomme *le détachement du sujet* (*avec trace démonstrative* dans le premier et deuxième exemple). Et on note qu'il est écrit :

> L'emploi de la trace démonstrative est plus fréquent dans la langue familière que dans la langue soignée.

Mais ça ne veut pas dire que la trace démonstrative est exclue de la langue soignée. Par exemple, on trouve cette phrase :

> ça obtient tout ce que ça veut, un député de l'opposition (A. Daudet)

Qu'on peut aisément mettre dans une subordonnée conjonctive en gardant le registre :

> Il faut bien admettre que ça obtient tout ce que ça veut, un député de l'opposition.

Quand au subjonctif, il ne change rien à la règle. On le conserve si la proposition subordonnée le nécessite :

> J'aimerais tellement que ça, ce soit mon avenir.
>
> Je cherche un stagiaire qui, lui, soit meilleur que vous.
>
> Je gravirai l'Everest, à moins que ça aussi, ça ne soit pas possible.
>
> Tu veux que moi, je t'écoute parler pendant des heures ?
>
> Tu as peur que l'amour, ce soit la pire chose qui puisse t'arriver ?

Answer (score 2):

*ça c'est ma chaise, ça c'est mes livres* comme pour *c'est eux*, le verbe *être* devient 'invariant' : 
au lieu d'être naturellement rattaché aux objets qu'il désigne, il est rattaché à l'idée du sujet qu'il désigne, il les englobe dans un groupe.

> - "J'ai peur que ça, ce soit ma chaise" pour un français correct, avec de multiples intonations possibles.

À l'orale le verbe *être* n'est pas conjugué dans le parlé médiocre :

> - "J'ai peur que ça, c'est ma chaise", avec une  prononciation agressive, voire vulgaire, ou alors pour donner un effet comique.

*ça ce soit* n'est pas envisageable, ou alors pour un effet comique au second degré ; je ne me souviens pas l'avoir entendu ni au bureau ni dans les cafés.

Mais cela peut varier d'une région à l'autre, ou d'un milieu social à l'autre.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with cl-r that although “j’ai peur que ça, ce soit ma chaise” is correct when writing, it would not be heard/used orally.
(Some might even argue that “j’ai peur que” would permit/require the “ne expletive” or the "non-negative ne" in formal usage giving: “j’ai peur que ça, ce NE soit ma chaise” to mean the same positive idea [i.e., “I’m afraid that’s my chair], but as an Anglophone my ear is not good at all in recognizing/understanding this weird use of NE, so I’ll try to avoid further mention of it, but I will put it in brackets [NE] in any subjunctive clauses that might follow in case formal use would still require it).

Personally, even in writing, I’d look for ways to avoid “… que ca, ce [NE] soit…,” even to the point of avoiding  both “ça” and “ce” completely with:

“j’ai peur qu’elle [NE] soit ma chaise” or, to keep the idea of “ce”:

“j’ai peur que celle-ci (or “celle-la”) [NE] soit ma chaise.”

Orally, you could ignore the subjunctive as cl-r suggests with "J'ai peur que ça, c'est ma chaise," but you could possibly maintain the subjunctive while remaining somewhat informal (and maybe “somewhat” incorrect, but no more so than going without the subjunctive, IMO) with:

“j’ai peur que ça soit ma chaise”

(please note that here, in this informal oral setting, I don’t even propose the [NE] in brackets, but maybe you could use it if you were after the comic effect to which cl-r refers).

Regardless, I appreciate your politeness! In that situation j’ai peur que je [NE] lui dise:

« Hey mec, dégages ton Q,  t’es dans ma chaise ! »